# IONIC 4: ionic cordova build android --prod --verbose não compila

Tags: ionic4

Quando uso o comando ionic cordova build android, o programa compila perfeito mas só acrescentar --prod que não compila. No erro diz que a estrutura do programa mudou durante a geração do código :

> Error: Internal Error: The structure of the program changed during codegen.

Esse código criado em 2018/2019, no ionic 4, de lá pra cá, o ionic evoluiu, o cordova tb. Tentando recriar a situação da época, reinstalei o node usando NVM , puxei a versão node de 2019, e instalei o ionic e o cordova. Fiz um upgrade de todas as dependências, pq precisava do cordova 9 para uma atualização de plugin. Essa atualização deu problema no SQLITE, custei a consertar, entretanto, acho q a solução passa por entender o q compilar o app para produção (--prod) faz exatamente pq a compilação sem ele não dá problema algum e o app roda no celular perfeito. Preciso do --prod pq a google play store não aceita app em versão debug.

Vejam o resultado da tentativa de build abaixo:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --verbose
  ionic:bootstrap local CLI 4.12.0 found at D:\dev\guiatijucano\node_modules\ionic\package.json +0ms
  ionic:lib Terminal info: { tty: true, ci: false, windows: true } +0ms
  ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'android' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, prod: true, project: null, '--': [] } +20ms
  ionic:lib:project Project type from config: Ionic 2/3 (ionic-angular) +0ms
  ionic:lib:project Project details: { configPath: 'D:\\dev\\guiatijucano\\ionic.config.json', errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'ionic-angular' } +5ms
  ionic Context: { binPath: 'D:\\dev\\guiatijucano\\node_modules\\ionic\\bin\\ionic', libPath: 'D:\\dev\\guiatijucano\\node_modules\\ionic', execPath: 'D:\\dev\\guiatijucano', version: '4.12.0' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Using config.xml: D:\dev\guiatijucano\config.xml +0ms
  ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic cordova build' [ 'android', '--prod', '--verbose', '--interactive', '--color' ] +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:project:ionic-angular:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +0ms
> ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android
[20:49:58]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.4
[20:49:58]  build prod started ...
[20:49:58]  clean started ...
[20:49:58]  clean finished in 75 ms
[20:49:58]  copy started ...
[20:49:59]  deeplinks started ...
[20:50:01]  deeplinks finished in 1.85 s
[20:50:01]  ngc started ...
[20:50:41]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[20:50:41]  Error: Internal Error: The structure of the program changed during codegen.
Error: Internal Error: The structure of the program changed during codegen.
    at AngularCompilerProgram._updateProgramWithTypeCheckStubs (D:\Dev\guiatijucano\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:466:19)
    at D:\Dev\guiatijucano\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:148:23[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

        ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android exited with exit code
        1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: process.exit received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +4ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 12832: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 12832 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "12832" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:257:5)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 12832 /T /F' } +471ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 12832 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "12832" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:257:5)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 12832 /T /F' } +15ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: exiting (exit code 1) +5
```

Acredito q esteja acontecendo alguma incompatibilidade nos pacotes. Fiz um npm outdated e fiz um upgrade até o limite suportado pelas versões.
Abaixo se vê um extrato do arquivo package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device-motion": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device-orientation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.9.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cordova": "^10.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "9.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device-motion": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^4.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^2.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "5.1.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.12",
    "emulator": "0.1.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic": "^4.12.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@ionic/lab": "^3.2.10",
    "typescript": "~4.1.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device-motion": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
      },
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {}
```

e o ionic info

```
Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 9.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, (and 12 other plugins)

System:
   NodeJS : v11.1.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```